# ErrorHandler::handleError - Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, newrelic

I used New Relic for debug my application and my big problem about spending time is a ErrorHandler::handleError. I don't know what is it.

I've set in my "Core.php" "Configure::write('debug', 2)" but didn't show any error.

Tks.

Felipe Marques

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you're just starting with CakePHP, I would suggest to start with the basics, get to know the framework and *don't* start to use advanced, custom and/or external tools until you understand the basics.

`ErrorHandler::handleError` is the default ErrorHandler that is used by CakePHP. This section of the documentation describes how to create your own ErrorHandler;

[Creating your own Error-handler](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/errors.html#creating-your-own-error-handler)

You may be able to create an Error-handler that 'hooks' into the functionality of New Relic. I'm not aware of an existing plug-in that does this, but Google may be your friend here.

Comment: Glad I could help. Good luck with your project!